# Apple has rejected my app because of the use of a social login

Tags: ios, app-store, facebook-login, appstore-approval

Apple's message

> Moreover, we found that your app uses Sina and Tencent Weibo login for authentication purposes only - but does not include any account-based features offered by that site. This is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.It would be appropriate to modify your app to include account-based features of that social network - or use your own authentication mechanism.

I don't know what is meant by "include account-based features of that social network". How can I fix this?

Sina and Tencent Weibo is the same as Facebook or Twitter.

Comment: I think it means, you're using the 3rd parties as an authentication method, but you don't use them for anything else. Are you using Sina and Tencent Weibo for anything other than authentication?

Comment: Just add something like get profile picture from logged service.

Comment: @SametDEDE is this enough? We have this feature but still get rejected.

Comment: @Himmators After 3+ years later maybe i can not recall correctly, but in that time some of my apps was just using authentication and getting user profile picture features. Those wasn't using Sina or Tencent Weibo but Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Google+ etc. I don't know, maybe you can ask Apple for detailed explanation of rejection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some additional features like sharing content with friends or similar which actually provides a reason for you to require the user to login. If you already have that feature, reply to the rejection with details about where in the app that function is.

Comment: I think you are right. I have to add sharing function in the next version. In this version, I have to remove this social authentication function